# javascript (Im assuming) dialog box customization

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio

Where can I find the code for the dialog box? I would like to have a dialog box for the password textbox as well.

[image]

Comment: The pop-up comes from the browser because the input has type "email"

Comment: I see, so the browser is actually doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `"this field is required"` by using attribute `"required"` like:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="password" name="psw">
</form>
```

if you want custom message on password field you can do so by native javascript alert like:

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["psw"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("Password is required");
        return false;
    }
}
```

or you can use jquery plugins to show custom message with custom styling with `sweet alert`

see this link for more http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/